# why does routerLink generate 'broken' url inside hyperlink

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have this button with routerLink directive and it works fine when I click on it:

```
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" [routerLink]="['/companies', id, 'departments', 'edit', t.id]">Edit department</button>
```

then I have this hyperlink:

```
<a class="nav-link" routerLink="['/companies', id, 'departments']" routerLinkActive="active">Show departments</a>
```

When I hover it the created url is not what I expected.

Url I had: `http://localhost:4200/#/%5B'/companies'%2C%20id%2C%20'departments'%5D`

1.) Why is the output of the link/url creation by the routerLink different? Both scenarios must created a valid/usable url to navigate to.

2.) How can I fix that?

Answer (score 5):

You have to use brackets for both situations, otherwise it just parses the string you put in:

```
[routerLink]="['/companies', id, 'departments']"
```

Comment: argh... it worked before because of hardcoded url like ="/companies"  now I introduced the dynamic id and I need the binding on the routerLink! Thanks for being my glasses!

Comment: you are welcome :) as you can see, i'm using some awesome glasses. *points at hat*